# Completely remove Android Studio, Eclipse and all the libs/packages installed with them

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, uninstallation

I am having a couple errors with gradle and sdk manager, so I would like to make a clean install of android studio.

How do I completely remove Android Studio, Eclipse and all the libs/packages installed with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing Android Studio:

1. Remove the Android Studio folder, usually in `/home/[username]/android-studio`
2. Remove `.AndroidStudioPreview` from `home/[username]`

Remove Eclipse from Software center.

Answer (score 7):

In Windows you also need to enable displaying of hidden files and folders and delete the following:

*users/${yourUserName}/appData/Local/**Android***