# Android Studio gutter preview for drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, preview, gutter

I didn't even know about this gutter color/drawable preview feature until recently saw it on another computer "turned on" by default...

Anyway, back to my workstation, I try to enable the feature but have no luck.

Basically, for example, when I open colors.xml, my screen looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii3Wn.png

In my settings, I think I have the required options checked to enable gutter preview:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbynS.png

So where is my color/drawable preview in gutter? They are not shown both in xml and Java files.

Thanks/BR/Richard

Comment: I expect to see something like this: http://androidpanic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Color-Preview.png

Comment: This may happen because the directory containing your XML file is not recognized as a resource directory. Could you please show a more complete image of your project structure?

Comment: If the colors.xml is not in a recognised resource directory, I should not be able to reference them in java/xml with R.color/R.drawable. I am also creating a new project in Android Studio to test out this gutter preview problem, and this is what the project structure looks like: http://i.imgur.com/B5HEqGG.png

Comment: It's strange that your screenshot does not show icons for some of the directories. Did you take it while Android Studio was rebuilding indices? Are there any exceptions in the log file?

Comment: It was in "Android" view. The whole project view looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/JsTYHnf.png. Android Studio was not in indices/gradle building process. The project was newly generated by Android Studio. Having done anything to any source files except adding new colors in colors.xml to test gutter preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to fix my gutter preview problem!

Basically, I remove all preferences of my installation (I was planning to completely remove and reinstall my copy of Android Studio). I figured something might messed up during number of updates over same copy of installation since very first preview release!

On Mac OSX, I followed the following steps: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio). Note that I had the latest copy of Android Studio already, so I simply just followed those steps to remove all preferences, and ran Android Studio.app again. Android Studio will prompt a Wizard page to step through setups just like it were new installation.

I haven't tried on my work Windows machine yet. A quick search shows steps required to remove Android Studio on Windows completely: [Completely remove Android Studio, Eclipse and all the libs/packages installed with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676896/completely-remove-android-studio-eclipse-and-all-the-libs-packages-installed-wi).

Comment: by all preferences what do you mean ?